# SwiftUI, call function in view after something happens in UIViewRepresentable

Tags: swift, swiftui

When the `searchBarButtonClicked` delegate method is called for my UISearchbar, how do I call the `refresh()` function in my view class?

**SearchBar: UIViewRepresentable**

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct SearchBar: UIViewRepresentable {

@Binding var text: String

class Coordinator: NSObject, UISearchBarDelegate {
        @Binding var text: String

        init(text: Binding<String>) {
            _text = text
        }

        func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
            text = searchText
        }

        func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
            searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }
    func makeCoordinator() -> SearchBar.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(text: $text)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SearchBar>) -> UISearchBar {
        let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: .zero)
        searchBar.delegate = context.coordinator
        searchBar.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = false
        searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
        return searchBar
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UISearchBar, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SearchBar>) {
        uiView.text = text
    }
}
```

**MyView: View**

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyView: View {
    @State private var searchTerm: String = ""

    func refresh() {
        //how do i call this function from `SearchBar`?
    }

    var body: some View {
        SearchBar(text: $searchTerm).padding(.top, 5)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very un-SwiftUI-ish, why do you want to call `refresh`? What actions are you planning to do there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve this using `NotificationCenter`

1. **Notification Extension**

   ```
   // MARK: - NSNotification
   extension NSNotification {
       static let SearchPressed = NSNotification.Name.init("SearchPressed")
   }
   ```
2. **Add Observer to onReceive**

   ```
   var body: some View {
       VStack {
           //...
       }.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSNotification.SearchPressed)) { _ in
       self.refresh() }
   }
   ```
3. Add this `Notification post` to the delegate method: `searchBarSearchButtonClicked`

   ```
   NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.SearchPressed,
       object: nil, userInfo: nil)
   ```